# For actions in a user profile more than a year ago the year should be visible

Tags: bug

When viewing a user profile for a mostly inactive user (For example, [akmad](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/67/akmad?tab=activity&sort=all)), the activity displayed goes back multiple years, but there is no year value for "ancient" activities and it does not make sense.....

[image]

Note how in the above picture, it appears the sort-order is wrong because the Jan 12 stuff happens *after* the Jan 19 stuff (and the Jan 19 stuff actually happens in different years - making it look like the user got Yearling badge twice in a year?). Also, the Dec 17 stuff appears to happen after the Dec 24 stuff).

To be consistent with other date values in Code Review Stack Exchange, the dates older than a year should have the actual year value displayed, so the Dec 17 date should be unchanged, but the Dec 24 date should include the year 2015, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a [meta-tag:feature-request]?  I see it on SO as well.

Comment: @Jamal [meta-tag:bug] tag info says: _"Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed."_ ... I Consider this both erroneous and unexpected - it is giving misleading information. There's a big difference between saying "I joined the site on the on the 31st October", and "I joined on the 31st October 2013".

Comment: @rolfl Jamal is right that it's global issue of every SE site. This has been [asked on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163792/346987) with [tag:feature-request] tag.